# How to check the property elementAt() has a value and its not null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Sometimes the elements that I am checking against do not exist and the application throws an error.

```
if(responseSerialNumber.ElementAt(1) == 0)
{
    //Do the following
}
```

How can I do deal with this?

Comment: What is the type of `responseSerialNumber`?

Comment: `ElementAtOrDefault`?

Comment: its an arry of bytes

Comment: `if (responseSerialNumber.Length >= 1 && responseSerialNumber[1] == 0) {...}` if `responseSerialNumber` is an  array.

Comment: What **exactly** does "do not exist" mean in this context? Does it mean that there aren't 2 elements in the collection? That the second element is `null` (in which case it shouldn't throw an exception when comparing to 0). Can you clarify *which* exception you get?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways of solving this problem.
First, just check if the array has enough elements before accessing:

```
if(responseSerialNumber.Length > 2 && responseSerialNumber.ElementAt(1) == 0)
{
    //Do the following
}
```

The second way is to use [`ElementAtOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault) which returns the appropriate default value based on the type of the array.

```
var item = responseSerialNumber.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
if (item != default(byte)) { // or use "(item != null)" if item is an reference type
   //Do the following
}
```

**BEWARE:** The second solution would work fine if you have an array of non-value types (in this case they can have null as default value). If you have byte array, stick with the first solution.

Comment: Since `responseSerialNumber` is byte array I think `item != 0` should be `item != default(byte)`?

Comment: in case of `ElementAtOrDefault` we can have `0` in *two different cases*: when `responseSerialNumber` is *too short* (e.g. empty) and when `responseSerialNumber[1] == 0`. Please, note that *empty array* will be *false positive*

Comment: ElementAtOrDefault is quite powerful for such cases, but it will also return the default value if we try to access an index which is out of bounds. For the sake of completness it might be interesting to add that the default value is always based on the type of the array. So for reference types it will be null and for value types the corresponding default value (byte = 0, int = 0 etc.)

Comment: @SelimYıldız, you're correct, but default(byte) is also 0 :). But anyways, I've updated the answer to make it prettier :)

Answer (score 1):

If `responseSerialNumber` is an *array* `byte[]` (see comments) you can check the *array*: first for its `Length` then for the `value`

```
if (responseSerialNumber.Length >= 2 && responseSerialNumber[1] == 0) {
  ...
}
```

Or (for arbitrary `indexAt` and `valueToTest`):

```
if (responseSerialNumber.Length >= indexAt + 1 &&
    responseSerialNumber[indexAt] == valueToTest) {
  ...
}
```

In *general* case (when `responseSerialNumber` is `IEnumerable<T>`) for given

```
int indexAt = 1;
valueToTest = 0;
```

we can `Skip` `indexAt` items and check the very next one:

```
if (responseSerialNumber.Skip(indexAt).Take(1).Any(item => item == valueToTest)) {
  // responseSerialNumber has at least indexAt items
  // indexAt's items is equal to valueToTest
}
```

Or even

```
if (responseSerialNumber.Where(index, value) => 
      index == indexAt && value == valueToTest)) {
  ...
}
```